# Android Circular movement of Gallery Items with Indicator

Tags: android, geometry, image-gallery, viewflipper

I am having issue with movement of images in a gallery with an Indicator at the bottom. For more clear idea about what I want to achieve you can find it here [link](http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/65/). I tried with ViewFlipper, I am able to get the images to move in circular way but not able to add the indicators like how its shown in the above link. There should not be any user interaction with it. The images should keep changing after 2secs of time interval and along with it the indicator also should change. Please help me. If anybody worked on this. Any sample code would be very much helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you tried using timer. use it with view flipper. I did it with it.

Comment: I did with Handler and ViewFlipper. Now the images are moving. But how do I places those dots at the bottom when one image is brought to front.

Comment: I need the same requirement and I've found any solution yet. Please share the solution whenever you find it. thanks